# firefox & object moved to here

Tags: asp.net, flash, firefox

We have an asp.net website that uses a flash movie to do HTTP file uploads, it works seamlessly on IE. When using firefox, it fails to upload .. HTTP debugging revealed that the page we are posting to returns the following:

HTTP 302

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="%2fproject_name3%2fDefault.aspx%3fReturnUrl%3d%252fproject_name3%252ffiles%252fuploader.aspx">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

This has been bugging us for a while and would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be the Flash cookie bug: Flash always send IE cookies regardless of browser. This is a problem for example when you are using Forms Authentication:

1. The user login which create a Session cookie.
2. The user access a Flash component (e.g. an upload component) that makes requests to the server and the requests access Session or is affected by Forms Authentication.

Call 2 will fail since there are no session cookie sent to the server since the session cookie is in Firefox's cookies and Flash is sending IE:s cookies. In your case it seems that the user is redirected to a login page (which seems to be /default.aspx).

Solution to this problem is to make the Flash component send cookies as post parameters and then recreate the cookies in a HttpHandler from the post parameters. I can post some sample code if you need it.

This is a common problem with SwfUpload component that I use a lot. I also use it inside umbrao so I also recreate umbraco's login cookies.

Update: here is source code of the HttpModule that I use:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace cimkey.utility
{
public class SwfUploadModule : IHttpModule
{
    private NameValueCollection paramNameToCookieName;

    private void BuildParamNameToCookieNameList()
    {
        if (paramNameToCookieName != null)
            return;

        // ASP.NET session.
        const string session_param_name = "ASPSESSID";
        SessionStateSection SessionSettings = (SessionStateSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/sessionState");
        string session_cookie_name = SessionSettings.CookieName; // "ASP.NET_SESSIONID";

        // Forms authentication.
        const string auth_param_name = "AUTHID";
        string auth_cookie_name = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;

        paramNameToCookieName = new NameValueCollection
        {
            {   session_param_name,     session_cookie_name }, 
            {   auth_param_name,        auth_cookie_name }, 
            {   "umbracoMemberLogin",   "umbracoMemberLogin"}, 
            {   "umbracoMemberId",      "umbracoMemberId"   }, 
            {   "umbracoMemberGuid",    "umbracoMemberGuid" }
        };
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        BuildParamNameToCookieNameList();

        context.BeginRequest += context_BeginRequest;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* Fix for the Flash Player Cookie bug in Non-IE browsers.
        * Since Flash Player always sends the IE cookies even in FireFox
        * we have to bypass the cookies by sending the values as part of the POST or GET
        * and overwrite the cookies with the passed in values.
        *
        * The theory is that at this point (BeginRequest) the cookies have not been ready by
        * the Session and Authentication logic and if we update the cookies here we'll get our
        * Session and Authentication restored correctly
        */

        try
        {
            foreach (string paramName in paramNameToCookieName.Keys)
            {
                string cookieName = paramNameToCookieName[paramName];

                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[paramName] != null)
                {
                    UpdateCookie(cookieName, HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[paramName]);
                }
                else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[paramName] != null)
                {
                    UpdateCookie(cookieName, HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[paramName]);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    static void UpdateCookie(string cookie_name, string cookie_value)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get(cookie_name);
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            cookie.Value = cookie_value;
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Set(cookie);
        }
        else
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie(cookie_name, cookie_value);
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Modify it to keep track of your cookies, it currently check cookies for

- ASP.NET session
- Forms Authenticatio
- Umbraco cookies

It checks for both post and request parameters. You client side code must make sure that these parameters are sent to the server (I send these parameters in a jQuery ajax POST call).

Comment: Yes, we do use forms authentication and I believe this is the actual issue. Of course code samples would be very helpful :)